# How can I display image in pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Please I need help for my client demand this work in 3 days and I am stuck with displaying image in pug template. Basically, the image have been uploaded fine as I see it in uploads, and even in the `img(src"")` I can see it as I right click and search the property but the image is not coming out, i.e is not displaying from the sketch box. I try reducing the sise but did not work. please help...

index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express()
    var path = require("path");
    //multer object creation
    var multer  = require('multer')
    var fs = require("fs");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
           fs.mkdir('./uploads/',(err)=>{
           cb(null, './uploads/');
        });
            //cb(null, path.join(__dirname +  '../public/uploads'));
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); }
    })
     
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
     module.exports = function(app){
    //GET home page. 
    app.route("/").get(function(req, res, next) {
      res.render( path.join(__dirname + "/../views/index.pug"));
    });
     
    app.route("/profile").post(upload.single('avatar'),function(req, res) {
      var image = req.file;
      console.log(image);
    res.render(path.join(__dirname + "/../views/index.pug"), {image: image})
    });
     }
```

index.pug

```
 html
   head
    title nanas personal portfolio
    script.
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funtion(event){
        document.querySelector("img")
          img.style.height = "50px";
          img.style.width = "50px";
          display = "block"
      })
    meta(name='description', content='Profile')
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/public/style.css')
    header     
    img(src='./uploads/' + image)
    div.profile-picture
      label choose/upload profile pic
      br
      form(action="/profile", accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg",  method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        input(type="file", id="file", name="avatar")
        br
        input(type="submit", value="upload")
        br
```

uploads

```
uploads/1631587019615nysc.jpg
uploads/1631587019615nysc.jpg
uploads/1631587019615nysc.jpg
uploads/1631587019615nysc.jpg
```

Comment: Where is the `<body>` element?

Comment: body was not included, are you saying i need the body to display the image

Comment: Sean i have find a way to convert object to string. That is the file to string and render it to pug, i can actually see it now but is the file property that appear instead of the picture it self. what can i do to convert those properties to picture instead.

Comment: What do you get? In your browser, go to View Source (usually Ctrl U), and paste the contents to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. The only way I was able to solve it is by using the image file in the public folder and not in assets. It also depends on how you have the server configured.
The way to write is as they told you in previous answers, I also leave you a link: https://dev.to/jh3y/pug-in-5-minutes-272k

I hope it helps you. - Gerva

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', './src/public');
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `=` , the code is `img(src='image.png')`

I'm not .pug developer, I just seen codes from here : https://nodejsera.com/library/pug/pug-images.html

Comment: ohh! thanks Aakash1282, i drop that part since i have so much headache, and the client was rushing me. i hope to pick that as a personal challenge after the client delivery.

Comment: Keep coding up 